# Где найти уроки по LWJGL 3?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, lwjgl

Хочу почитать действительно интересные и глубокие уроки по LWJGL 3. Но в сети нигде не могу найти, гугл молчит, официальный сайт предоставляет только английский

Comment: Я бы еще посоветовал в сторону libGDX посмотреть.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Answer (score 1):

Почему молчит? Уроки есть и их довольно много по [запросу](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lwjgl%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8):

- [Пикабу](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOn77G_KvMAhVLEpoKHZnuCBMQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpikabu.ru%2Fstory%2Flwjgl_urok_2_3675849&usg=AFQjCNGGcQ__Yml6sbaKRfp47MXx_raDZg&sig2=5AGVQ6BwW46VSrUIVk4jDw) (внезапно)
- [gcup](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjOn77G_KvMAhVLEpoKHZnuCBMQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgcup.ru%2Fpubl%2Fgamedev%2Furoki_po_lwjgl_chast_iii_obrabotka_sobytij_sushhnosti%2F1-1-0-572&usg=AFQjCNH_CZK6Ix6KTC-JiUcM04_RZhKukg&sig2=Fem_Ld-4ts31bNyCKM-G9A&cad=rja)
- А [тут](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOn77G_KvMAhVLEpoKHZnuCBMQtwIIYTAJ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvk.com%2Fvideo-27035376_171157556&usg=AFQjCNHyAhDvlR-vncrkTJ9XNYKMpx7HRw&sig2=LerDrG05rFRYxHgkI0v5bg) даже Flappy Bird пишут на нем
- Аналогичная тема на [киберфоруме](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-gui-javafx/thread607417.html)

и т.д.

Ищите, ищите и еще раз ищите, все есть, если хорошо искать.

Comment: Flappy Bird видел. На gcup идея хорошая, но остальные, на пикабу например, для версии `lwjgl 2.0`, это уже не то, что 3 версия. Киберфорум аналогично, версия 2

Comment: @Herrgott но лучше учите английский, без англа прогер - плохой прогер, а плохой прогер - голодный прогер :)

Comment: ну ладно, с английским я еще может как-то смирюсь, но уроков найти не могу. Gcup тоже только для старой версии. А на официальном сайте используют `maven`, а я не знаю с чем его едят, да и пока не хочется знать

Comment: По запросу **"lwjgl 3" tutorial** много чего находится, должно быть полезно. Советую начать с видеоуроков, если есть возможность воспринимать англ с речи.

Comment: Вот я как-то больше по письменной речи